# Why Is My JS Code Not Working-An Obect Expected Error On Line 1 Keeps Appearing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a js script for a school project that opens some pages, but it keeps giving me the object expected error in my windows script host. [Error Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQG7d.png) Please help!

```js
var x = prompt("What page do you want to go to?");
if (x === 1) {
    window.open("C:\Users\laura\Desktop\ATOMICSTURCTUREPRESENTATION\Page1.html", "_self");
}
else {
    if (x === 2) {
         window.open("C:\Users\laura\Desktop\ATOMICSTURCTUREPRESENTATION\Democritus.html", "_self");
    }
        else {
            if (x === 3) {
                 window.open("C:\Users\laura\Desktop\ATOMICSTURCTUREPRESENTATION\Dalton.html", "_self");  
            }
            else {
                 window.open("C:\Users\laura\Desktop\ATOMICSTURCTUREPRESENTATION\JJThompson.html", "_self");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the `JS` file directly?

Comment: see the user privilege, provide the current user with administrative privilege, or change the folder path. might the issue get resolved

Comment: Can you show us the HTML file you are using this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Object Expected problems in JavaScript is due to the problem of DLL files in your system: jscript.dll and vbscript.dll. If these two DLL files missed, then usually there will be Object Expected problems in JavaScript websites.
>
> If your computer still has these two DLL files, please take the following steps to fix Ojbect Expected problems in JavaScript:

1. Click “Start Menu” – “Run”, and enter “regsvr32 jscript.dll”, then click yes;
2. Click “Start Menu” – “Run”, and enter “regsvr32 vbscript.dll”, then click yes;

> Tips: You can download JScript.dll and VBScript.dll here, and unzip them to c:\windows\system32\

3. If the upper two steps notified you success, it means your IE objects’ problems are fixed successfully. And then use Advanced SystemCare Free to empty the history and cookies in Internet Explorer. Then there will be no more Object Expected problems in JavaScript.

> And if there is nothing succeed, then please take the following steps that may fix Object Expected JavaScript problems:

1. Reset Internet Explorer or other web browsers. “Tools”, “Internet Options” “Advanced”, “Restore Defaults”. If this step can’t solve JavaScript Object Expected problems, then take the next action.
2. Reinstall Internet Explorer.
3. if the second step doesn’t work either, then the only thing for you is to reinstall whole system.

**Copied from:** [blog.iobit](http://blog.iobit.com/object-expected-problems-javascript_311.html)

**Another thing**

`prompt` returns a string so do this:

```
if (x == 1) {
```

3 equal signs mean that the value and the data types ate equal, and 2 equal signs mean that only the values are equal

Comment: While this will fix the issue of the if statement not working the way he wanted, it doesn't answer the question he asked.